# sys.exit() does not exit program when catching exceptions

Tags: python, exit, sys

This program checks molecular formulas. I want the program to exit as soon as it detects an error in a formula. For example, the formula "a", is incorrect.
When I run it through my code:

```
def readletter():
    if q.peek() in string.ascii_lowercase:
        print(q.peek())
        return q.get()
    else:
        raise Formelfel("Förväntad liten bokstav.")

def readLetter():
    if q.peek() in string.ascii_uppercase:
        print(q.peek())
        return q.get()
    else:
        raise Formelfel("Förväntad stor bokstav.")

def readAtom():
    X = ""
    try:
        X += readLetter()
    except Formelfel:
        print("Missing capital letter at end of row "+getRest())
        sys.exit()
        return

    try:
        x = readletter()
        atom = X+x
    except (Formelfel, TypeError):
        atom = X

    if atom in ATOMER:
        return
    else:
        raise Formelfel("Okänd atom.")

def readGroup():
    if q.peek() in string.ascii_uppercase or q.peek() in string.ascii_lowercase:
        try:
            readAtom()
        except:
            print("Unknown atom at end of row "+getRest())
            sys.exit()
```

I get this output:

```
Missing capital letter and end of row a
Unknown atom at end of row
```

Why is this? I called `sys.exit()` before `print("Unknown atom at end of row "+getRest())` so why does it still execute? I want only the first row of the output to be printed.

Comment: No, you did not. `print(...)` comes before `sys,exit()` in your code.

Comment: This is _exactly_ why `except:` is usually a bad idea…

Comment: @Tichodroma He means that `sys.exit` was called after printing the first message, but the second message was still printed.

Comment: By the way, why `return` after `sys.exit()`? What were you hoping that would do? I know in CLC-Intercal you can "ABSTAIN FROM GIVING UP WHILE STILL GIVING UP" to emulate quantum computing, but I don't think that works in Python…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sys.exit` raises a `SystemExit` exception. You are catching it with your `except` clause.

What you should do instead is catch a more specific class of exceptions, which does not include `SystemExit`.

Catching `Exception` will work:

```
def readGroup():
    if q.peek() in string.ascii_uppercase or q.peek() in string.ascii_lowercase:
        try:
            readAtom()
        except Exception:
            print("Unknown atom at end of row "+getRest())
            sys.exit()
```

You can learn more about exceptions and `SystemExit` [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/exceptions.html#base-classes).

---

Note that you should ideally catch something more specific than `Exception` (which is very broad, and may catch exceptions you don't intend to catch).

Comment: Brilliant! I wrote `except Formelfel`, and it solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because in python exit event is processed as `SystemExit` exception